# Add condition to transition using script runner

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I am using the scriptrunner plugin for Jira.

Is it possible to add a condition to a transition using scriptrunner?

Currently, my condition is in a script which I have manually added to the workflow.
But I was wondering if there is a way to do it automatically?

I was looking through documentation on: https://docs.atlassian.com/

I came across this method: 
[replaceConditionInTransition](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/8.6.0/com/atlassian/jira/workflow/WorkflowManager.html#replaceConditionInTransition-com.opensymphony.workflow.loader.ActionDescriptor-java.util.Map-java.util.Map-) which is a method of `WorkFlowManager`.

But I'm unsure on how to use this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Conditions as any another scripts can be added from file system. You can store scripts in any VCS (bitbucket, github, gitlab, etc) and automatically deploy them to Jira server file system through any CI/CD system (teamcity, jenkins, bamboo, gitlab, etc).

So, as result process will be looks like. 1. commit changes in you script to vcs 2. wait a bit for auto deploy (e.g. triggered by commit) 3. done. As additional you can write any script/service/etc for commit these changes automatically if needed.

Also look at [script roots](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/5.7.2/jira/#_script_roots) it's helpful way which allows reuse any of script fragments through helpers classes.

It's rather conceptual answer basically because implementation is depends on environment, but I hope that you get at least one more point of view to solve this task.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using the Java API to modify Jira workflows is pretty tough. You could dig around in the workflow editor to see how conditions are added there. Remember that you have to do this in a draft workflow and then publish it, which takes some time in large projects

I like the idea of replacing a script file as easier, if it can be done when no issues are transitioning